# The item in my title will not centre

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I am trying to make a title page for a report, and everything comes out great, except for the one line (Lecturer:John Doe) that does not want to centre properly. My code:

```
\title{ 
\normalfont \normalsize 
\textsc{Some place} \\    [25pt] 
\horrule{0.5pt} \\[0.4cm] 
\huge Assignment \\ 
\horrule{2pt} \\[0.5cm]  
Lecturer: John Doe
\newline
{\Huge 2014}
\date{}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding one line of `horrule` of 0pt, right below the John Doe, solves the problem. Since the OP did not provide the macro of `horrule`, this solution assumes it was a horizontal line with a certain width, as displayed below

```
\newcommand{\horrule}[1]{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{#1}}
```

After this is added, the `not centering` phenomena was observed and therefore, the proposed solution makes it centered.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\newcommand{\horrule}[1]{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{#1}}

\title{
\normalfont \normalsize 
\textsc{Some place} \\    [25pt] 
\horrule{0.5pt} \\[0.4cm] 
\huge Assignment \\ 
\horrule{2pt} \\ [0.5cm] 
Lecturer: John Doe
\horrule{0pt}   % <--- Here
\newline
{\Huge 2014}
\date{}
}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you for the quick but thorough answer.

Comment: does OP stand for Optional Package?

Comment: Nay, OP=Original Poster.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{report}
\title{
\normalfont \normalsize
\textsc{Some place} \\    [25pt]
\hrule 
\vspace{0.4cm}
\huge Assignment \\[0.4cm]
\hrule 
\vspace{0.5cm}
Lecturer: John Doe\\
\Huge 2014
}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}
  \maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `titlepage` environment:

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}
  \begin{titlepage}
    \centering
    \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
    {\scshape Some place \par}
%    \par
    \vspace{1em}
    \rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}
    \par
    \vspace{0.4cm}
    {\huge Assignment \par}
%    \par
    \vspace{0.4cm}
    \rule{\linewidth}{2pt}
    \par
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    {\huge Lecturer: John Doe
    \par
    2014 \par
    }
    \vspace{\stretch{2}}
  \end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image]